# How to use a global variable in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create a single instance of a class that should be available to all my controllers. It's a bit like a shopping cart in a system with only one user. I have been using the session state for this but it times out after a while and that's a problem.

I'd consider using Application State and wiring it up in global.asax. Is that how things are done in MVC or is there an approach that fits better with the framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a singleton. Have the class with a class method to return itself if it detects that has already be allocated.  Other allocate itself and return itself.  Go here for some info on exactly how. http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking up the System.Runtime.Caching namespace as it give you the ability to cache variables in memory for as long as you need.

However i would probably if it was me store the data in a data source of some description.